# J-METER FILE SAVING ISSUE

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I installed j-meter and tried to get a test report then i got the following error and  couldn't save the file ...after selecting options < look&feel and changing the theme it worked!!!!
i want to know what is the reason behind this ? can any one explain?

ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.computeFileName(Save.java:201) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:163) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a bug either in the [Darcula Theme](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula/issues) or in [JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/) or in [JMeter](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&order=relevance%20desc&product=JMeter&query_format=specific). In the latter case you might want to try out the [nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html) to see if the issue is still there.

I cannot reproduce your issue from the description so you need to specify exact steps and provide comprehensive environment information (operating system, Java version, any JMeter Plugins installed, etc.)

If changing look and feel helps you - you can make the change permanent by manipulating `jmeter.laf` property, i.e. if you put the following line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
```

you won't see this "beautiful" dark theme on next start of JMeter

Also it is possible to generate HTML Reporting Dashboard using JMeter command-line, without the GUI:

- Run test and generate dashboard:

  ```
   jmeter -n -t -f test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard
  ```
- Generate dashboard out of the existing [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode):

  ```
   jmeter -f -g result.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard
  ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Look and Feel configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Generating Reports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)